# Should we have the tags "algorithm-request" and "model-request"?

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging

There are many questions on our site that of the form (for example, [this one](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/2787/2444))

> Which algorithm/model can potentially solve this task X successfully?

This question is a bit problematic, because, unless you already solved the same or a similar problem, the best answer will probably be only an "educated guess" of the algorithm/model that would be appropriate to solve task X. For example, if someone is dealing with images, then convolutional neural networks may be a good first choice, but, who knows, maybe CNNs are not the best solution for this specific task, so this educated "suggestion/recommendation/guess" (which is not necessarily an "opinion") may not actually be appropriate, although, initially, it looks reasonable. So, this type of question is problematic because of what I just said, but it's a recurrent one, and, often, people need some guidance in order to solve a problem.

Assuming that this type of question is on-topic here, should we have the tags

- [algorithm-request](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithm-request)
- [model-request](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/model-request)

for this type of question?

This would allow users to have the list of all such questions in one place, so that they can eventually search for a question that they also have before asking a duplicate one.

Or maybe we should use the existing tag [reference-request](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) for these questions too? I think that references are papers, books or any other source of information that can support something (e.g. a claim, quote, etc.), as the dictionary puts it

> reference: the use of a source of information in order to ascertain something:

So, I don't think that algorithms and models are "references", so we shouldn't use that tag for these questions.

This question is related to [this one](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1695/2444).

Comment: Yep I think such tags make sense

Comment: @DennisSoemers In [this case](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/26039/2444), which tag would you use? I think that in this case all of these 3 tags would be potentially applicable.

Comment: Hrmmm I'd guess `model-request`, if that also covers things like architectures and not just requests for already-trained models with their trained parameters. Otherwise... `algorithm-request`?

Comment: @DennisSoemers Yes, I guess model-request, but sometimes it's not very clear, that's why I was wondering about your take on this one.